# Javascript addEventListener function

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

I am new to Event Handlers and I have come across a code that is written below

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    initialiseMediaPlayer();
}, false);
```

Is there any difference in writing the same code as

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseMediaPlayer();, false);
```

Ultimately we are calling the same function, so does it make a difference or is there some advantage in writing it in the manner above?

Comment: The latter won't do what you think

Comment: The latter is a syntax error

Comment: You are passing the return value of initialiseMediaPlayer to the event listener.  Remove the invocation () and they will be the same

Comment: @danronmoon up to the return value

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    initialiseMediaPlayer();
}, false);
```

Will execute `initialiseMediaPlayer` when the dom content is loaded.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseMediaPlayer();, false);
```

is a syntax error; if you remove the semicolon:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseMediaPlayer(), false);
```

calls `initialiseMediaPlayer` immediately, then passes the return value (which likely *isn't* a function) to `addEventListener`. This won't act as desired.

---

You can do

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseMediaPlayer, false);
```

(remove the parentheses = function call). Then `initialiseMediaPlayer` will be executed on dom content loaded, and act as desired.

However, unlike in the former case, `initialiseMediaPlayer` will actually receive the arguments given by the browser. Also, its return value is received by the browser. In case of `DOMContentLoaded`, most likely this doesn't matter much.

You also avoid creating one extra anonymous function if you pass `initialiseMediaPlayer` directly. Again, the effect is not really perceptible from the user's standpoint.

Comment: What if initialiseMediaPlayer receives parameters?

Comment: @montogeek that parameter will be an [event object whose most notable property is the document it points to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). I can bet you the initialiser won't even notice there is an event object being passed to it.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, using .bind solve my problem.

Answer (score 10):

1). Yes there is great difference. The second version will throw an error. But even if you fix it like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseMediaPlayer(), false);
```

`initialiseMediaPlayer` will not be called on `DOMContentLoaded` because `()` make it execute immediately, while you have to pass a referece to a *function*, not its result.

2). Another significant difference is the **context of invocation**.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseMediaPlayer, false);
```

`initialiseMediaPlayer` will be invoked in the context of `document` object. While the first version will be called in `Window` object context.

Comment: sounds a little confusing but it makes things much clearer..thanks a lot

Comment: Context means that `this` will refer to the different objects inside your function.

Answer (score 8):

The second argument on the `addEventListener()` function accepts *type function*. So you cannot pass `initialiseMediaPlayer();` because that is a function invocation.

What you can do is:

```
var onDOMContentLoaded = function() {
    initialiseMediaPlayer();
};
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDOMContentLoaded, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that it was the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    initialiseMediaPlayer();
}, false);
```

the anonymous function `function(){initialiseMediaPlayer();}` is registered to be triggered when the document's event 'DOMContentLoaded' gets triggered

in the second case:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initialiseMediaPlayer();, false);
```

what is registered as the event listener is the result of the expression `initialiseMediaPlayer()`

so, yes, there is a difference :)