# javascript code is not working

Tags: javascript

This code is not working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script>
document.getElementByID("button").addEventListener('click', outInfo, false);
function outInfo () {
var user =  document.getElementById("userName").value;
alert(user);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>User Name:
<input id="userName" type="text"/>
<input id="button" type="button" value="Click Me" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

This code is working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script>
<script>
function output() {
var i = document.getElementById("input");
window.alert(i.value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>User Name:
<input type="text" name="username" id="input" size="30"/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Start" onclick="output()" />
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

What's wrong with the first one? I suppose the problem is with a function "outInfo".
Which way is the best to solve such problems?

Comment: Elements don't exist yet. Add script before closing `body` tag.

Comment: Please make the title more descriptive. "Code is not working" is very vague.

Comment: Move the script tag to right before `</body>`

Comment: Which browser/version are u running this in?

Comment: Possible example...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255801/javascript-addeventlistener-function

Comment: Waht does 'is working' and 'is not working' mean? Be sure to be clear about what it is you're trying to do and not just paste a bunch of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the javascript referring to an element before the document fully loads.

Do this:

#### HTML

```
<body onload='onLoad()'></body>
```

#### JS

```
function onLoad() {

  // ... Now manipulate my DOM
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', outInfo, false);

}
```

Comment: Great! Consider accepting my answer if this did cause it to work out.

Answer (score 0):

The element doesn't exist yet, when you try to bind the event to it.

You have to run the code after the element has been created, either by putting the code somewhere after the element:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="Start" onclick="output()" />
<script>
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', outInfo, false);
</script>
```

Or by using the `load` event that happens after the page is completely loaded:

```
document.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', outInfo, false);
};
```

Note also that it's `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`.

Comment: very helpful answer - "Or by using the load event that happens after the page is completely loaded:"