# Script is working in jsfiddle but not in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm trying to create an extension for Chrome Browser. It should include options where the behaviour of an newly created tab can be chosen (e.g. opening the tab in background or in foreground). The setting should be stored with localStorage.

As I'm new in programming JavaScript, I took the example code from http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options and tried to customise it. This is what I have so far, and it is working (which means the chosen radio button is saved when page is reloaded) in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yczA8/

I was really happy to see it working. But after having created and loaded the Chrome extension, it wasn't working any more. Also opening the html-File in Chrome Browser doesn't show the same behaviour as it does in jsfiddle. Why not? Where's the problem?

This is my popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
      body {
        min-width: 200px;
        min-heigth: 100px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
     <h3>Neuer Tab im:</h3> 
    <form method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="tabVerhalten" value="tabVordergrund" />Vordergrund
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="tabVerhalten" value="tabHintergrund" />Hintergrund
    </form>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>

    </body>
</html>
```

This one is **popup.js**:

```
// Saves options to localStorage.
function save_options() {
    var tabVerhalten1 = document.getElementsByName('tabVerhalten')[0].checked;
    var tabVerhalten2 = document.getElementsByName('tabVerhalten')[1].checked;

    var tabVerhaltenIndex;

    if (tabVerhalten1) 
        tabVerhaltenIndex = 0;
    else if (tabVerhalten2) 
        tabVerhaltenIndex = 1;

    localStorage.setItem("tabVerhalten", tabVerhaltenIndex);

    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "&Auml;nderungen gespeichert.";
    setTimeout(function () {
        status.innerHTML = "";
    }, 750);
}

// Restores select box state to saved value from localStorage.
function restore_options() {
    var storedVal = localStorage.getItem("tabVerhalten");
    if (!storedVal) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementsByName('tabVerhalten')[storedVal].checked = true
}

restore_options();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', save_options);
```

and finally the **manifest.json**:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TEST",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "STM",
    "description": "Description",
    "permissions": ["contextMenus", "tabs"],
    "background": {"scripts": ["script.js"]},
    "icons": {"16": "16.png", "48": "48.png", "128": "128.png"},
    "browser_action": {"default_icon": "48.png", "default_popup": "popup.html"}
}
```

Comment: What is your error? When you open your extension, right-click on the mini-page and click inspect element. Then go to console and see if any error is logged

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null popup.js:35

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255801/javascript-addeventlistener-function

Comment: Thanks, I solved the error in line 35. Now there is the same error message for the very last line of popup.js, where I can't solve the problem with the explanation mentioned in your link - the error message remains.

Comment: just try `document.getElementById('#save').addEventListener(...);`

Comment: Using "document.getElementById('#save').addEventListener("click", save_options);" also leads to "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addEventListener' of null"...

Comment: There I made changes to my answer (the one at the bottom). Doesn't throw any errors for me now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    restore_options();
    }, false);
```

I MADE THE FOLLOWING CHANGES:

I removed `method="post"`
I moved `<script src="popup.js"></script>` after all the other script
I changed the parameters for the `addEventListener()` method

HERE ARE THE CHANGED SCRIPTS

**popup.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <style>
      body {
        min-width: 200px;
        min-heigth: 100px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
     <h3>Neuer Tab im:</h3> 
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="tabVerhalten" value="tabVordergrund" />Vordergrund
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="tabVerhalten" value="tabHintergrund" />Hintergrund
    </form>
    <div id="status"></div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
// Saves options to localStorage.
function save_options() {
    var tabVerhalten1 = document.getElementsByName('tabVerhalten')[0].checked;
    var tabVerhalten2 = document.getElementsByName('tabVerhalten')[1].checked;

    var tabVerhaltenIndex;

    if (tabVerhalten1) 
        tabVerhaltenIndex = 0;
    else if (tabVerhalten2) 
        tabVerhaltenIndex = 1;

    localStorage.setItem("tabVerhalten", tabVerhaltenIndex);

    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = "&Auml;nderungen gespeichert.";
    setTimeout(function () {
        status.innerHTML = "";
    }, 750);
}

// Restores select box state to saved value from localStorage.
function restore_options() {
    var storedVal = localStorage.getItem("tabVerhalten");
    if (!storedVal) {
        return;
    }
    document.getElementsByName('tabVerhalten')[storedVal].checked = true
}

restore_options();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {restore_options();}, false);
button_thing = document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click',function() {save_options();}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, the error message is solved for this code line. But I get the same error message for the very last line of popup.js, where this solution doens't help.

Comment: @user3432234, just use `getElementById()` instead: `document.getElementById('#save').addEventListener(...);`

Comment: @user3432234, well firstly I'll assume you are using the same method for your second error as well. And secondly, in your html file, try moving the `<script src="popup.js"></script>` after you have created the button (id=save).

Comment: This is currently the last line: "document.getElementById('#save').addEventListener('click', save_options);". Is this correct or have I misunderstood you? Additionally, I moved the <script></script> to the last line before </body> in the html file as recommended.

Comment: `document.getElementById('#save').addEventListener('click',function() {
    save_options();}, false);`

Comment: This is exactly what I did before when you mentioned the link to another question. But still, the same error massage occurs

Comment: I'll try reproducing your problem on my computer. I'll get back to you in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, in JSFiddle you are running the **JS-code onLoad** and in your files you are running the **JS-code in the header**.

*If you change it in your JSFiddle, it's no longer working as you can see here: [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yczA8/1/)*

So, what can you do to solve this issue?

There are different ways, I'll recommend to load your JS-code on load, like JSFiddle does. To do this, add the [onload event to your body tag](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp). There you call a function named 'loadMyScript();' or something like this:

```
<body onload="loadMyScript();">
```

For the next step, you have the choice: You can put your whole code in the loadMyScript() function or you import your script with the loadMyScript() function. I didn't test those ways, so I can't tell you which one is working better or which one is simpler but you should try the import-script-way first, because I think this could avoid issues.

**Little example of the import-script-way:**

```
<head>
    <script>
        function loadMyScript() {
            var js = document.createElement("script");
            js.type = "text/javascript";
            js.src = "popup.js";
            document.body.appendChild(js);
        }
    </script>
    <!-- YOUR HTML HEAD HERE -->
</head>
<body onload="loadMyScript();">
    <!-- YOUR HTML BODY HERE -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works when opening the popup.html. But not in the chrome extension:
Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".
Can I include loadMyScript() in popup.js? (Well, I tried it but it didn't work - but propably I didn't implement it correct?)