# Why does the browser trigger my onclick funtion?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am trying to create an onclick event(javascript), what takes input data from an HTML form, by pressing a button. I am using a window.onload function in my JS file.
My form looks like:

```
<div class="set-the-clock">
    <form name="settheclock">
        <span>Hours: </span><input type="text" name="fhours"><br>
        <span>Minutes: </span><input type="text" name="fminutes"><br>
        <span>Seconds: </span><input type="text" name="fseconds"><br>
        <input type="button" id="send" value="Enter">
    </form>
```

My onclick event:

```
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click",setTheClockByButton());
```

and my setTheClockByButton():

```
function setTheClockByButton() {
    alert("wtf");
    setTheClock(setHour, setMinute, setSecond);

}
```

and when I press view in google chrome,the alert with the wtf comes up, so it seems my button is clicked by "itself", and I got no clue why :(

Comment: I remember (maybe bad but I remember) that in some browsers when submit button is missed and there is only one button, it works like submit form. Maybe is a glitch related to this? Just a suggestion, so that I just comment it

Comment: you are executing your event handler instead of passing it as a reference `setTheClockByButton()` should be `setTheClockByButton` in the `addEventListener` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis in `setTheClockByButton()`, when you create a function you are actually setting a variable.  The long hand for creating a function looks like this.

```
var functionName = function() {
    //Your code here
};
```

Therefore to assign a function to a handler, you must use the functions **variable** name, but to call the function you add the parenthesis.  In this case you need simply the variable name so it would look like this.

`document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click",setTheClockByButton);`

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `setTheClockByButton()` when you set the event listener. Leave off the `()`.

```
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click",setTheClockByButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parenthesis in `setTheClockByButton()` such as :

```
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click",setTheClockByButton);
```

It doesn't work because with those parenthesis you are calling the function instead of binding it to the event.

For more details about basic usage of `addEventListener` you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15256031/1980659).